# Non-blocking subprocess and catch the output of each subprocess

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess, popen, python-multithreading

so I got this tricky situation which I need to execute few subprocess and be able to get each subprocess output.
This is what I'm using atm:

```
output = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
output = output.communicate()[0]
```

Which works really well and also getting me errors, if there are any.
Now I need to execute like 10 of those and be able to get the output of each one of them. I was wondering if there is a smooth way of doing that WITHOUT using multithreading.

Comment: Maybe use `select` module? It allows you to wait for input on several file-like objects at once. Take a look at `select.poll` and `select.select`.

Comment: sounds like overkill, but eventbased approach e.g. Tornado http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/process.html#tornado.process.Subprocess could help. This wraps select/epoll/poll/kqueue

Answer (score 1):

`subprocess.Popen` starts the child process asynchronously, only `communicate` makes the operation synchronous.

So you just have to first launch all your children processes. Then depending on how you want to process their output, you can:

- if you need to process output in a ordered manner, that is display output from cmd1, then cmd2, ... just use `communicate` or `wait` for each child command
- if you need to process output as soon as it is available and you use a Linux or Unix-like platform, you could use the `select` module.
- if you need to process output as soon as each command ends and want to support Windows platforms, you could just loop with `subprocess.poll` on child processes to know which have finished.
- if you need more, you are likely to have to use threading